# Javascript code freezes page for a while -- how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a fairly CPU-intensive script which, when run, freezes the whole page for a while, so that it can't be scrolled or clicked, etc. I would gladly sacrifice performance for a more smooth experience.

Also, in my case, this script is a part of Google Chrome extension.

**Is it possible to make a script that freezes the page run in background, without interrupting user interaction with the page?**

Comment: Either split your long running code up into several, sequential function calls or use a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) are of interest.

It would be best to put CPU-intensive task into a worker, which does its job in the background. Another solution is to cut your code into pieces, load them asynchronously and execute them one after another.

http://blog.typekit.com/2011/05/25/loading-typekit-fonts-asynchronously/

Comment: The uncertain tone of your answer makes this more of a comment.